# How do I can add watermark to rtmp flow?

Tags: ffmpeg

I encode udp flow to `rtmp with ffmpeg`, and I wand to add watermark from `png` file, this `png` file changes every second.

I tried

```
ffmpeg -i test.ogv -acodec copy -vf "movie=a_test.png [wm];[in][wm] overlay=5:5 [out]" -ac 1 -y output.ogv
```

but `ffmpeg` doesn't add updated png file. How I cat do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with use drawtext `ffmpeg -i test.ogv -vf "movie=a_test.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/3[water];[water] drawtext=fontsize=25:fontcolor=Yellow:textfile=1.txt:reload=1:x=(w)/2:y=(h)-25[out]" out.ogv`